# Short form toast in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

When I create applications in the Kotlin language, I create the Utils class and there I create a method for showing Toasts in the whole project. My code looks like this:

```
fun Context.showToastShort(text: String, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) {
    Toast.makeText(this, text, duration).show()
}

fun Context.showToastLong(text: String, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_LONG) {
    Toast.makeText(this, text, duration).show()
}
```

Now I want to do this in a Java project. How do I implement such a method in Java? I don’t understand how I can expand my method using context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that, you can use a class like this.

```
public class MyUtils {

    private Context mContext;

    public MyUtils(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void displayToast(String message, int lenght){
        if (lenght == 0){
            Toast.makeText(mContext,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Create an instance of the class whit context and call anywhere like this.

```
MyUtils myUtils = new MyUtils(getContext());
myUtils.displayToast("Hello world",0);
```